# How to make dynamic field in PIG relation

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig relation with 3 fields As:

```
A = Load 'record.txt' as (name chararray,ID int,subject chararray,flag boolean);<br>
DUMP A;

( RAM,222,JAVA,true)
( RAM,111,DotNet,false)
( RAM,444,HTML,false)
( SAM,777,DotNet,true)
( SAM,333,JAVA,false)
```

How to generate extra field as reference with concatenation of name and ID ,
when flag is true otherwise it will be the repetition until next true comes, as below :

```
( RAM,222,JAVA,true,RAM-222)
( RAM,111,DotNet,false,RAM-222)
( RAM,444,HTML,false,RAM-222)
( SAM,777,DotNet,true,SAM-777)
( SAM,333,JAVA,false,SAM-777)
```

Use below script but it didn't give exact result .

```
A = Load 'demo.txt' as (name chararray,ID int,subject chararray,flag boolean);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE name,ID,subject,flag,CONCAT(name,ID) As reference;
DUMP B;

( RAM,222,JAVA,true,RAM-222)
( RAM,111,DotNet,false,RAM-111)
( RAM,444,HTML,false,RAM-444)
( SAM,777,DotNet,true,SAM-777)
( SAM,333,JAVA,false,SAM-333)
```

What should be the CONCAT function Or Any other way to get exact result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = Load 'demo.txt' as (name chararray,id int,sub chararray,flg boolean);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE name,id,sub,flg,CONCAT(name,ID) As rf;

split B into b1 if flg=='true', b2 if flg=='false';  
C = join b2 by name left outer,b1 by name;
C1 = foreach C generate b2::name as name,b2::id as id,b2::sub as sub,b2::flg as flg,b1::rf as rf;

Result = union b1,C1;
```

Hope this will help!!